# TextInput layout show error without floating the label

Tags: android, material-design

Can anyone please help to solve the edittext label floating issue, As per my requirement the hint text should be there in editbox itself when error text is displayed. Right now what is happening that whenever I show the error text the label also moving, i don't want to move the labeluntil and unless user start typing

The screenshot was taken from google design screen
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-single-line-text-field
[image]

Comment: Can you share your xml file?

Comment: added my xml,please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/ti_keyword_error"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/defaultLayoutPadding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/defaultLayoutPadding"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/adv_top_padding">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_keyword_search"
            style="@style/match_wrap.white_hint.no_focusable"
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_white"
            android:hint="@string/m_adv_keyskills" />


    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I have checked the code , this is the default behavior fo TextInputLayout

```
final boolean hasText = mEditText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditText.getText());
        final boolean isFocused = arrayContains(getDrawableState(), android.R.attr.state_focused);
        final boolean isErrorShowing = !TextUtils.isEmpty(getError());

        if (mDefaultTextColor != null) {
            mCollapsingTextHelper.setExpandedTextColor(mDefaultTextColor.getDefaultColor());
        }

        if (mCounterOverflowed && mCounterView != null) {
            mCollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextColor(mCounterView.getCurrentTextColor());
        } else if (isErrorShowing && mErrorView != null) {
            mCollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextColor(mErrorView.getCurrentTextColor());
        } else if (isFocused && mFocusedTextColor != null) {
            mCollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextColor(mFocusedTextColor.getDefaultColor());
        } else if (mDefaultTextColor != null) {
            mCollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextColor(mDefaultTextColor.getDefaultColor());
        }

        if (hasText || isFocused || isErrorShowing) {
            // We should be showing the label so do so if it isn't already
            collapseHint(animate);
        } else {
            // We should not be showing the label so hide it


      expandHint(animate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as setting hintEnabled to false:

```
textInputLayout.isHintEnabled = false
```